# jquery animation on firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, cross-browser

I'm trying to do a simple animation on div items, everything works fine on Google Chrome, Safari and Firefox 4, but on Firefox 3 everything goes in unexpected way (div positions messes around and etc ). 
Maybe you know how to solve this issue and make it smooth?

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5FLQ/208/

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not like `display:inline-block;` Instead use

```
display:inline;
float:left;
```

### Check it out at http://jsfiddle.net/Q5FLQ/250/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this plugin, I think can help you

http://desandro.com/demo/masonry/docs/animating-jquery.html